# Installed Forca Theme, wonder how I can alter Post editing screen

Tags: plugins, custom-taxonomy, screen-columns

I've just installed [Forca Theme](http://themeforest.net/item/forca-responsive-newsmagazine-theme/5657130) on my fresh WP installation.

They add a few custom taxonomies like:

1 Events Categories - Just categories for Events

2 Events - Same as regular Post, with custom behaviour and template, have assigned Events Categories to it

3 Events Page - Lists ALL Events, no possibility to display from particular Events Category because the Event Page is not associated with ANY Category, it's the Events (Items) themselves that are assigned to categories.

So what I want to do is to add the same Category assignment box from Events to Events Page screen which looks like this:

[image]

And is assigned like this:

```
register_taxonomy("events-cat", 
                        array("Events Categories"), 
                        array(  "hierarchical" => true, 
                                "label" => "Events Categories", 
                                "singular_label" => "Events Categories", 
                                "rewrite" => true,
                                "query_var" => true
                            ));

register_post_type( 'events-item',
    array( 'labels' => $labels,
         'public' => true,  
         'show_ui' => true,  
         'capability_type' => 'post',  
         'hierarchical' => false,  
         'taxonomies' => array('events-cat'),
         'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'custom-fields', 'page-attributes') ) );
```

In `/includes/register.php` so I tried to add a new taxonomy registration to POST screen according to documentation I've found:

```
register_taxonomy("post-events-cat",
    array('post'),
    array(  "hierarchical" => true,
        "label" => "Post Events Categories",
        "singular_label" => "Post Events Categories",
        "rewrite" => true,
        "query_var" => true
));
```

But well, it didn't work.

So I wonder how I can tweak particular screen in Wordpress? Not even really related to the Theme itself.

Thanks

Comment: Even if you get that box added, how do you expect it to work? It is doubtful that the page templates will adjust to the change automatically.

Comment: That would be a good start for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want [`register_taxonomy_for_object_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy_for_object_type) to add the taxonomy to the "Page" post type.

```
register_taxonomy_for_object_type('events-cat','page');
```

As noted, I don't know how you expect this to work. You are going to have to alter the page templates.

I would also suggest that you look into the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy), in particular [the part about custom taxonomies](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display). It sounds like you may be reinventing Core functionality.

Comment: Of course I will tweak page templates and hook into some of the parts of my interest, my only bottleneck was adding new UI/taxonomy? to existing default Page/Post screens.

Comment: @Fratyr : I told you how to do that in the first sentence.

Comment: It worked. All is good now ;)